# multiple parent Entities with one child entity in EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, parent-child

there are tow entities `Post` and `Photo` . both have a collection of `comment` entity .

is there anyway to avoid the `mapping` written below (being have to define **one** property for **each** parent in `Comment` entity ) ?

```
public class Post
{
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments{get; set; }
}

public class Photo
{
    public string Path{get;set;}
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments{get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public int? PostId{get;set;}
    public Virtual Post Post{get;set;}

    public int? PhotoId{get;set;}
    public Virtual Photo Photo{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
public class PostBase{
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments{get; set; }
}


public class Post:PostBase
{
    public string Title {get; set;}

}

public class Photo:PostBase
{
    public string Path{get;set;}

}

public class Comment
{
    public int? PostBaseId{get;set;}
    public Virtual PostBase PostBase{get;set;}

}
```